# Меняется тип после компиляции

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

```
EquippableItem addEquippableItem;
itemDatabase.items.Add(addEquippableItem.GetCopy());
```

добавляется предмет в базу данных, всё ок, тип EquippableItem, но если я ещё раз скомпилирую скрипты, то тип меняется на Item.

https://youtu.be/twUn_xXmS6M

UPD: при запуске сцены тип так же меняется

Answer (score 1):

Тут всё просто и сложно одновременно :)

Дело в том, что в Unity вы видите не сами ассеты, а их десериализованные с диска версии. Перезапись данных на диске осуществляется, когда вы нажимаете Save Project, а перезагрузка после остановки PlayMode или после компиляции кода проекта.

Это просто пояснение почему у вас отваливается тип именно в эти моменты.
А теперь, собственно, почему он вообще отваливается - `List<Item> items`

Дело в том, что при сериализации базовыми средствами Unity такого листа на диск - записываются только данные, которые соответствуют базовому классу. Если вы откроете файл .asset с помощью текстового редактора, то сами всё увидите.

В итоге, при перезагрузке данных вы получаете список базовых предметов.

Выхода здесь, собственно, два (из тех, что сразу приходят в голову) - разделять списки, либо хранить пары - ключ-данные. Т.е. в вашем списке будет храниться что-нибудь вроде таких классов:

```
class DataPair
{
    public string Type; //тут хранится, например, typeof(EquippableItem).ToString()
    public string Json; //а тут JsonUtility.ToJson(addEquippableItem)
}
```

А когда начинаете отрисовывать ваш скрипобъект, либо запускаете рантайм - конвертируете эти данные в объекты. Хорошо может помочь интерфейс [ISerializationCallbackReceiver](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.html) он позволяет отлавливать события связанные с сериализацией.